# releasing mutex giving object synchronization error while using with Lock in multi threaded application in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

Given part of code undergoes with approx thousands of thread at at time, monitored with SemaPhoreSlim. While logging I am using lock and Mutex as shown below. I tried to maintain that the same Thread would release the mutex, but it is not as I am getting object synchronization error in some of the Threads.

```
    lock (thisLock)
        {
            try
            {
                taskMutex.WaitOne(1000);
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }
            var tile = Path.GetFileName(resourceFile.FilePath);
            if (tile != null)
            {
                logFile.Debug($"Updating status {tile.FileName}");
                if (tile.Status == "Re-Processing" && processRetey < 3)
                {
                    processRetey++;
                    goto Process;
                }
                tile.Status = "Downloading";
                Utility.UpdateXML(FilePath, tile.Status, configuration);
                PfcTile tilePfc = new PfcTile(configuration);
                tile = tilePfc.Add(tile);
            }
            taskMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
```

Comment: That `goto Process;` looks deeply suspicious...

Comment: I agree. Also, locking before attempting to acquire a mutex means that other threads will not be able to access anything protected by that same lock while this thread waits for the mutex to become available. If the lock is used only for this piece of code, it is redundant as the mutex provides the same reentrancy protection. Finally, you'll do yourself a favor by using try..finally to ensure that the mutex is released after use even when exceptions occur.

Comment: Thanks for all your comment. I just covered taskMutex.ReleaseMutex(); with a try catch block and skipping the object synchronization error. This approach is working for me for now. Please tell me if this could generate another issue in future.